# How to use houndify API with curl

Tags: houndify

I just want to test houndify API simply by curl application.
But I can't find how can I use it.
If I send text or voice recoded file to houndify by curl application in windows(linux) pc, could you let me know full option for curl?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using an SDK to do your requests.  These SDKs allow for streaming of audio, have code examples, and take care of many things including authentication.
https://www.houndify.com/sdks

If you really want to use cURL or write your own SDK, you can find more details about the required fields here, but this would require calculating the authentication headers yourself. 
https://www.houndify.com/docs/advanced#basics-of-a-houndify-api-request